# Using `Rack::Session::Pool` over `Rack::Session::Cookie`

Tags: ruby, session, cookies, rack, pool

What are the different use cases of [Rack::Session::Pool](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Session/Pool) and [Rack::Session::Cookie](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Session/Cookie)?

As far as I understand (correct me if I'm wrong):

- `Cookie` stores *all* the session key:value pairs directly within the cookie (marshalled)
- `Pool` only stores an id in the cookie, and maintains the rest of the session hash within `@pool`

So: what are the implications/reasons for choosing one over the other? what's `@pool`? Why does `Pool` need to expose a different public interface from `Cookie`? Why is the documentation so lacking?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right, `Session::Cookie` marshaling and store sessions in cookies.

`Session::Pool` instead keeps sessions in memory.

`Pool` has some advantages:

```
- faster, no marshaling needed 
- you can keep any objects with it(read ones that can not be marshaled)
```

But when you restart your app all sessions are lost.

With `Cookie` instead you will have restart-persistent sessions at the price of marshaling.

Alternatives - [Session::Memcache](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Session/Memcache), [Session::Mongo](https://github.com/migrs/rack-session-mongo)

Comment: Rack::Session::Moneta: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/minad/moneta/Rack/Session/Moneta also provides an abstract session store interface to a large variety of key/value stores