# Using a secret for cookies stored with Rack::Session::Pool

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

The [source](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb#L91) from `Rack::Session::Cookie` contains the following warning about not setting a secret to check for cookie integrity:

> No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
>   This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
>   provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
>   cookies.

When using the `Rack::Session::Cookie` module, you can set a secret in this fashion:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: 'change_me'
```

However, I'm using `Rack::Session::Pool`, which "provides simple cookie based session management." I'm assuming that I also need to provide it with a secret, but can't find a relevant example. The source code/documentation is not very helpful either. Does anybody know if this needs to be done, and how it would be accomplished if so?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573968/using-racksessionpool-over-racksessioncookie) on the differences between `Cookie` and `Pool`, it points out that only the "id" (actually a [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID)) is kept within a cookie and everything else is kept in memory. If the data is in memory then the requirement to generate a HMAC is a lot lower than if it had been stored in the cookie, and if you *really* needed that then I suppose it's been left up to you.

I had a look at [the source](https://github.com/rack/rack/tree/master/lib/rack/session), and [Pool](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/pool.rb#L31) does not look for a secret passed as an option, but [Cookie](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb#L91) does.

I believe from reading the source for `Pool` that it generates a unique SID each time, so no keys/id's from your data are exposed.

As a side note, if you're going to choose to use cookies, [encrypt them](https://rubygems.org/gems/encrypted_cookie).

Comment: `Pool` generates a new SID for each client for new sessions or if the `:renew` session option is `true`. Otherwise the same SID is used until the session expires (client stops sending cookie after expiration or session is invalidated/dropped on the backend).